# How to convert string to key value in python

Tags: python, arrays, django-models, key-value

I have a Django Application and want to convert a value from a string field which is comma separated to a key vaule pair and add it to a json data block.

```
class MyClass1(models.Model):
keywords = models.TextField(_('Keywords'), null=True, blank=True)
```

Example of list:

```
blue,shirt,s,summer,for women
```

The JSON data in my code

```
data = {
       "name": self.name,
       "type": self.type,
       ...
       "keywords": []
       }
```

I want to split the comma separated string of self.keywords and append it to the keywords field in my json, but as a array like this:

```
{
"name": keyword,
},
```

I do the split with the split function, but dont know how to create a key value pair as array and append to keywords.

Expected output:

```
data = {
       "name": "Name of item",
       "type": "Type of item",
       ...
       "keywords": [
        {
         "name": "blue"
        },
        {
         "name": "shirt"
        },
        ...
       ]
       }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the comma separated data looks like in the keywords field and the corresponding output? It's not clear how you want to map comma separated values to key/value pairs

Comment: Given your example data, is this what you want the keywords field of your JSON to look like - `"keywords": ["blue", "shirt", "s", "summer", "for women"],`?

Comment: @IainShelvington I add the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `.split()`:

```
data = {
    'name': self.name,
    'type': self.type,
    # …
    'keywords': [{'name': n} for n in self.keywords.split(',')],
}
```

It might however be better to work with a custom field. You can define such field with:

```
from django.db import models


class ListAsCharField(models.Field):
    def __init__(self, separator=',', *args, **kwargs):
        self.separator = separator
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        if isinstance(value, (str, type(None))):
            value = self.separator.join(str(x) for x in value)
        return super().get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value.split(self.separator)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = value.split(self.separator)
        return value
```

then you can use this in the model to automatically do the wrapping/unwrapping from a list:

```
class MyClass1(models.Model):
    keywords = ListAsCharField(
        max_length=256, verbose_name=_('Keywords'), null=True, blank=True
    )
```

Then you can process this with:

```
data = {
    'name': self.name,
    'type': self.type,
    # …
    'keywords': [{'name': n} for n in self.keywords],
}
```